# Options For Programmatic Control of a Sony a7r-ii

Tags: sdk, camera, sony

Is the remote camera SDK the only method for programmatic control of an A7R-II? I would prefer a hard wired solution, perhaps via the multi port. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Camera Remote API is the only way to control the camera.  Unfortunately there is no API support via a hard wired solution.

Comment: Are there any examples of using a Raspberry Pi via WiFi?

Comment: There are no examples of how to use the API with a Raspberry Pi, but as long as you connect to the camera's WIFI network if should not be a problem

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to the use the RaspPi via Wifi to control these cameras.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xR3gAfu4Hfw

Using:
https://github.com/mungewell/sony_camera_api

Remember to install the 'PlayMemories' app on your *camera*, the pre-installed one is pretty crappy (was on my HX60).